# Python decode from ascii hex

Tags: python, ascii

I'm looking for a function to convert "\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66" to "abcdef" in python, without having to print it

and is the proper term for this type of encoding ascii hex?

Comment: I'd call it "escaped hex" rather than "ascii hex". To me anyway, ascii hex would suggest something like "5A5B669F".

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> "\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66".decode('ascii')
u'abcdef'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert "\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66" to a unicode string with the `unicode` method:

```
unicode("\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66")
```

Output: u'abcdef'